# Fatal error when updating wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I updated avada to 5.0 and encountered an issue with child theme.
Can anybody help me out for a sec?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function avada_is_portfolio_template()
>   in
>   /home/manekine/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/header.php
>   on line 222

Site is: http://www.manekinekocasino.com

This is line 222 where the error is coming from:

```
if ( is_page_template( '100-width.php' ) 
     || is_page_template( 'blank.php' ) 
     || ( '1' == fusion_get_option( 'portfolio_width_100', 'portfolio_width_100', $c_pageID ) 
     || 'yes' == fusion_get_option( 'portfolio_width_100', 'portfolio_width_100', $c_pageID ) && ( 'post' == get_post_type( $c_pageID ) 
     || 'avada_portfolio' == get_post_type( $c_pageID ) ) ) 
     || ( avada_is_portfolio_template() && 'yes' == get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_portfolio_width_100', true ) ) 
     || '100-width.php' == $page_template ) 
{
    $main_css = 'padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;';
```

Answer (score 0):

They probably have renamed that function or removed it if it was working before the update just fine. Best way to know the answer is to get in touch with their developer though. You can check whether that function exists or not before calling it. Not the best way, but you'd get rid of the error :

```
if ( is_page_template( '100-width.php' ) 
 || is_page_template( 'blank.php' ) 
 || ( '1' == fusion_get_option( 'portfolio_width_100', 'portfolio_width_100', $c_pageID ) 
 || 'yes' == fusion_get_option( 'portfolio_width_100', 'portfolio_width_100', $c_pageID ) && ( 'post' == get_post_type( $c_pageID ) 
 || 'avada_portfolio' == get_post_type( $c_pageID ) ) ) 
 || (function_exists('avada_is_portfolio_template') && avada_is_portfolio_template() && 'yes' == get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_portfolio_width_100', true ) ) 
 || '100-width.php' == $page_template ) 
{
      $main_css = 'padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;';
```